# Add offset to pointer without casting to UINT

Tags: c++, pointers

If have written the following code to learn a bit about pointers and pointer arithmetic, meaning going from offset to offset to read something from a struct.
I have the following code

```
    DWORD * x = (DWORD*)((UINT)ptr1 + sizeof(int) + sizeof(float));
    float f = *(float*)x;
```

This Code works as it should. However I struggled a lot to get it working as at the beginning I was not casting `ptr1` to `UINT` and therefore was getting a different address as I wanted to have.

Now it works. However can someone explain to me why I cannot add the offset (`sizeof...`) to the `ptr1` directly which is of type `DWORD *` ?

```
DWORD * x = (DWORD*)(ptr1 + sizeof(int) + sizeof(float));
float f = *(float*)x;
```

Comment: Please add some more context. Should we guess what's the type of `ptr1`?

Comment: ptr1 + N == (char*)ptr1 + sizeof(*ptr1)*N. Look up pointer arithmetic tutorials.

Comment: But with proper C++ casts.

Comment: You should not cast to UINT - it is not large enough in 64-bit code.  Cast to `char *` instead.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ No need to guess.  The OP says "ptr1 ... which is of type DWORD *"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a number `n` to a `T *` pointer will move the pointer `sizeof(T)*n` bytes (not `n` bytes).

For your example, if we suppose that both `sizeof(int)` and `sizeof(DWORD)` are 4, adding `sizeof(int)` to `ptr1` will move `ptr1` 16 bytes (instead of 4, which you likely intended).

Comment: And the **reason** for this is arrays: `int x[10]; int* xp = &x[0]; xp = xp + 1;` and now `xp` is equal to `&x[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

> going from offset to offset to read something from a struct.

You can't do that. That's not how pointers work. You shall not treat them as just numbers, addresses; that way madness lies. C++ is an abstraction and you can only have a pointer to an object or an array of objects. Once you start playing around with it to navigate *between* objects, you've lost. Prepare for UB weirdness relating to padding, alignment, aliasing, optimisations...